# PHP Not changing color when equals the value

Tags: php, html

I have a quick question, I'm not sure what I have done wrong in this part of the code but every time Type(NUM) equals the value of the if statement.

I've tried with 2 pieces of data

ID 1 = Type(NUM) 2

ID 2 = Type(NUM) 1

But it's only going to the first if statement and stopping.

Picture of this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of4B6.png)

The code is;

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row["Commit"]== "test"){
        continue;
    }
    echo "<tr ID = \"cell\">";
    if($row['Type(NUM)'] = 1){

        echo '<td style="background-color:#ffab0a; font-weight:bold"> UPDATE</td>';
    }
    else if($row['Type(NUM)'] = 2){

        echo '<td style="background-color:#00cc00; font-weight:bold">NEW </td>';
    }
        else if($row['Type(NUM)'] =3){

        echo '<td style="background-color:#ff00ff; font-weight:bold"> FIX </td>';
    }
            else if($row['Type(NUM)'] =4 ){

        echo '<td style="background-color:#cc0000; font-weight:bold"> REMOVE </td>';
    }
    echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

U must use `$row['Type(NUM)'] ==  2` not '='

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($row["Commit"]== "test"){
    continue;
}
echo "<tr ID = \"cell\">";
if($row['Type(NUM)'] == 1){

    echo '<td style="background-color:#ffab0a; font-weight:bold"> UPDATE</td>';
}
else if($row['Type(NUM)'] == 2){

    echo '<td style="background-color:#00cc00; font-weight:bold">NEW </td>';
}
    else if($row['Type(NUM)'] ==3){

    echo '<td style="background-color:#ff00ff; font-weight:bold"> FIX </td>';
}
        else if($row['Type(NUM)'] ==4 ){

    echo '<td style="background-color:#cc0000; font-weight:bold"> REMOVE </td>';
}
echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
```

Comment: Tried that already and never worked... It keeps doing http://i.imgur.com/dnQPret.png

Comment: can you print_r the **$row** data and give me the result

Comment: Array ( [0] => Type(NUM) [Type(NUM)] => Type(NUM) [1] => Type [Type] => Type [2] => 1 [ID] => 1 [3] => asdasd [Commit] => asdasd [4] => asdasd [Developer] => asdasd [5] => 2017-03-12 [Date] => 2017-03-12 )

Comment: Array ( [0] => Type(NUM) [Type(NUM)] => Type(NUM) [1] => Type [Type] => Type [2] => 2 [ID] => 2 [3] => sadasdsa [Commit] => sadasdsa [4] => dsadad [Developer] => dsadad [5] => 2017-03-12 [Date] => 2017-03-12 ) Array ( [0] => Type(NUM) [Type(NUM)] => Type(NUM) [1] => Type [Type] => Type [2] => 1 [ID] => 1 [3] => sadasd [Commit] => sadasd [4] => asdasd [Developer] => asdasd [5] => 2017-03-12 [Date] => 2017-03-12 )

Comment: give me a screen shot of data

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this/

Answer (score 0):

you every time do the if you are making the $var to num use ' == ' instead of ' = '